# yum doesn't find php-apc

Tags: centos, apc

I'm trying to install apc (alternative php cache) on a centos 5 server. I tryed `yum search apc` and only finds American Power Company related packages.

How can I install apc?

Comment: Meanwhile I found that there was a filter to php* and that's why it did not show the php-pecl-apc.

Answer (score 12):

The package is called php-pecl-apc and it should be available in any of your repos.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much easier than the above!

Answer (score 5):

```
yum install php-pear php-devel httpd-devel pcre-devel gcc make
```

```
pecl install apc
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using remi repository. (CentOS release 6.5, PHP 5.4)
You can list the packages available by following command

```
yum --enablerepo=remi list php54*
yum --enablerepo=remi list php54* | grep apc
```

I got following apc package

```
php54-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64     4.0.7-1.el6.remi         @remi
```

Now you can use following command to install apc

```
yum install php54-php-pecl-apcu --enablerepo=remi
```